# How to keep two vectors of points in One vector

Tags: c++

I have a two vectors of `CvPoint` say

```
vector< CvPoint> pa, pb;
```

`pa` has 20 points and `pb` has 30 points;

I want to put both points in one `vector`, where first colum will have points of `pa` and second column will have points of `pb`.

So far, I declared a `vector` of both points like this:

```
vector <vector <CvPoint> , vector < CvPoint> >
```

I know it is not right. 
I am not getting how can I keep two vectors in one vector. 
Looking for guide.

Comment: A vector is a one-dimensional data structure. There are no "columns" in a vector. You can create a two-dimensional vector, perhaps, a `std::vector<std::vector<CvPoint>>`. Or use a `std::pair` or a `std::tuple`. Too broad.

Comment: vector < vector <CvPoint> >

Comment: An [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of two vectors?

Comment: Please elaborate as to the problem you are attempting to solve. Without more information as to why keeping two separate vectors is not acceptable, it will be very difficult to provide a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `std::pair` to have essentially a 2 column table of vectors;

```
std::vector<CvPoint> pa, pb;

...

std::pair<std::vector<CvPoint>, std::vector<CvPoint>> myPair(std::make_pair(pa, pb));

myPair.first == pa /* true */
myPair.second == pb /* true */
```